# Find $E(e^{aX})$ if $X \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\lambda, k)$

Tags: expected-value, gamma-function, moment-generating-functions, gamma-distribution

I am trying to calculate this:

> Let $X \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(\lambda, k)$.   If $0 < a < \lambda$, find $E(e^{aX})$.

I have attempted this by integration, I inserted a picture of my integral:

[image]

Because of the form of the integral I believe that I should take a constant out to change the $\lambda$ to $a-\lambda$ as that is what appears in the exponential, and then get the integral of the PDF of a $\operatorname{Gamma}(a-\lambda,k)$ random variable which integrates to $1$ and simplifies the expression, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for typesetting math here.

Comment: Are you assuming that $k$ is an integer here? If so there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: yes, thank you!